Using Neovide with nvr without launching it from terminal on Mac?
I looked up how to do so but the only solution I found was launching Neovide from the command line with NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS=/tmp/nvimsocket neovide foo.rs. I would like to use it and still launch Neovide from the dock, and then open files into buffers with nvr afterwards.

I found I can use this line of lua for nvim in Neovide to listen for nvr: vim.cmd(":call serverstart('/tmp/nvimsocket')").
